# create .flv from images

Tags: image, flv, actionscript-3, rtmp

I need some suggestions about to create .flv from 1000 images.

The application I'm building will be use flash to show the .flv, and the server, who have red5 rtmp and php5. The server will be do the conversion from .jpg to .flv.

I searching information but I didn't find which language can be the best to do conversion, or some examples about it...

Someone can help me?

Any idea from I can start it?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use ffmpeg library. It is very useful library for convertion.

Here is the link

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

You can run this command from your php code.And you can run it in a loop for all images.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

Also you can find many commands about ffmpeg here.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Comment: +1 it was your comment that made me try ffmpeg for myself.  Brilliant!  I am making FLV from a series of JPEGs and an MP3, and ffmpeg is the first solution I've found that works directly from one to the other, with no hassles. :)

Answer (score 1):

A thought: why do you have to convert the images in the first place? Why not just use Flash to display the images. [That can be done](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=90092) using ActionScript.

If the images are not the correct size, then use your application server to resize them before putting them in a location accessible to your Flash application.